# Error in 2-sided printing on Xerox WorkCentre 6400

Tags: printing, printer

We use a Xerox WorkCentre 6400 at work. When we print a odd number of pages in 2-sided mode the last one is printed on the wrong side (and wrong orientation) of the paper.

That is, e.g., if we print 3 pages on letterhead paper, we get pages 1-2 as expected (with our logo on the top of the front page) but page 3 comes out wrong (logo on the bottom and back side of the page).

I could not get any help from neither User's nor Administration manuals. Any idea on any configuration we are missing?

Comment: Assuming this happens in all programs (which you don't specify and may not have checked) then just update the printer driver or use an alternate.  This is very obviously a printer driver issue.  i.e. if you are using a PCL5e driver, try the PCL6 or Postscript, or even try one of the Universal drivers.

Comment: @Debra: It happens with Ghostview (on Windows 7) I haven't tested on anything else. I'll try to update the drivers if I can, or get someone to do it. Thank you.

Comment: What I'm suggesting, to be clear, isn't necessarily to update drivers but rather (assuming it's in more than one program) to switch to a different driver.  Xerox typically provides PCL5e, PCL6, and Postscript;  I've had best results with the Postscript driver, re. this type of issue, but YMMV.

Comment: @Debra: OK, I think I understood, more or less. I'll try to figure it out tomorrow at work. Please don't take me wrong, but it is somehow difficult to follow when I do not know what "PCL5e" means, nor "re.", nor "YMMV". I am Portuguese, my English is not that bad, but not that good either.

Comment: Good indication that the issue is in some versions of Ghostview/Ghost... here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/hplip/+bug/484928 . "YMMV" is the English phrase "your mileage may vary" meaning that your results may not be predictable from mine.  PCL5e and PCL6 and Postscript are all types of drivers used for printers, i.e. the commands that are sent to control the printer. Xerox & most printer companies usually offer several options on drivers;  PCL5e is the most basic & reliable, Postscript is the most supported, but options will work differently depending on the driver installed/chosen.

Comment: And if you go to http://www.support.xerox.com/support/workcentre-6400/downloads/enus.html?operatingSystem=win7x64  you will see the different drivers for this printer -- it spells out Postscript, PCL5c, PCL6 & you can download each and see whether one or another resolves the issue you have (though I now suspect it is in Ghostview & not the printer driver.)

Comment: @Debra: Thanks. We had support over there, they might indeed update something on the driver side, not sure what, sorry. The issue got fixed for now with a printer configuration (added it has an answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We did miss a configuration, so it was simpler that it looked at first.

We had to configure the paper tray to "letterhead" (it was set to "plain") and also choose letterhead when printing (I use it with GSView and Acrobat, on Windows 7).

This way it prints ok both 1- and 2-sided, using a single paper tray, depending only on the application's settings. Previously we had to use two trays.

Many thanks to @Debra and @hdhondt for the input

Answer (score 1):

When duplexing, a printer always prints in the following sequence:

page 2, page 1, page 4, page 3, etc.

You can easily verify this if your printer half ejects the page after the first pass. You'll see that the first page printed is page 2. It's done in this way to ensure that the pages exit in the correct order (i.e. 1,2,3,...) face down. This does not normally cause any funny effects, because normal paper is the same on both sides. Letterhead is different though, and both side and orientation are critical.

If you add a blank page at the end of your document, you'll find that the last page prints on the correct side.

Comment: Indeed, that is what we experience. Adding a 4th page (or 6th, or...) gets the work done. The problem is that it is not always simple to add a page.